# Testing strings for numbers and percents using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c

I've been trying this:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *testNumber=[NSNumberFormatter new];
    if (![testNumber numberFromString:someNSString])
```

I have been told that the `numberFromString` will return `nil` if `someNSString` is not a number.

However, I have found that if `someNSString` contains, for example, "5.9%", then this is assumed to not be a number, thus my test above passes, even though NSNumber itself can work with `5.9%` as a number just fine.

So how to elegantly test for numbers vs non-numbers when including percents as numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by "NSNumber itself can work with 5.9%"?

Comment: if I store the `floatValue` of a string that contains "5.9%", it is correctly stored at 0.059 in NSNumber. It can be retrieved and used as a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`-[NSScanner scanFloat:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanFloat%3a):

```
float testNumber;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:someNSString];
if ([scanner scanFloat:&testNumber]) {
    // A valid number, and it is stored in `testNumber`
} else {
    // Not a valid number, at least by floating-point standards
}
```

Of course, if you don't actually want it in a `float` at the end, substitute `-[NSScanner scanDouble:]` or `-[NSScanner scanDecimal:]`.

Note that your `floatValue` test isn't "including percents as numbers," it's simply ignoring trailing non-numeric characters.